# Use a redirect to include a # at end of URL

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site built with angularJS. I have not currently enabled hashbang urls or html5 mode. As such, the structure of the URLs are: `https://www.example.com/#/example`

I recently saw my site pop up on google (which I was very happy about). However, the url it directed me to excluded the required `/#/` e.g. `https://www.example.com/example`. Hence, I got a 404 error (which I was not very happy about).

So my initial reaction was to write a 301 redirect in my .htaccess file that attaches `#/` to any url that does not have it in.

However, I am unsure how to actually do it. If anyone knows how to write this, or has a more elegant solution your input would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi. I wasn't actually sure how to write the regex. I am not an expert at this and I couldn't quite get the stuff I found online. Sorry for asking for code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(example)$ /#/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

This literally redirects just `/example`. The `NE` flag is necessary in order to prevent the `#` (a special char) being percent encoded. The `$1` backreference matches the parenthesised subpattern in the `RewriteRule` pattern - in this case it's just "example" - saves you typing it twice! But when you introduce a more complex pattern (see below), this is mandatory.

Note that I've used a 302 temporary redirect above. Change this is to a 301 redirect when you are sure it's working OK. Temporary redirects are not cached by the browser, so it makes testing easier.

If you need something a bit more generic, then you'll need a pattern - but only make it as generic as you need. For example, to only match the letters a-z (lowercase) then:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /#/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, much appreciated! It is working perfectly for pages with lower case letters. I did have two questions though 1) If I want to include uppercase and numbers in this (I have some pages that are based on a numerical route parameter) would I use: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /#/$1 [R=302,L,NE]? 2) Why did you use a 302 redirect, most of the stuff I read spoke about 301 redirects? Thanks again!

Comment: 1) Yes that will work OK. You can also add the `NC` (`NOCASE`) flag ie. `[R=302,L,NE,NC]` to make the regex case-insensitive. 2) The 302 (temporary) redirect is just whilst developing/testing (added info to answer). The "problem" with 301 redirects are that they are cached by the browser, so if you make a mistake then the browser caches the mistake! Obviously in a live environment you do want the redirect cached (most of the time) so change it to a 301 when you've tested that it's working.

Comment: great thanks for all your help, all makes sense and works great. Thanks!